# Want to add homescreen icon for android chrome in my website

Tags: android, html, angular, google-chrome, homescreen

I want to add custom icon for website Built in Angular 10 homescreen menu after adding it to home screen from chrome `Add to Homescreen` menu

I have achived this in Iphone using this code
`<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="71x71" href="assets/icons/homescreen-icon/group.png" />`

But i am not able to figure out how to make it working for android.
I tried following things for android but none of them works

`<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icons/homescreen-icon/group.png" /> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/icons/homescreen-icon/group.png" /> <link rel="mask-icon" href="assets/icons/homescreen-icon/group.png" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this using these two line of code

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/icons/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="assets/icons/homescreen-icon.png" />
```

for android `shortcut icon` should be `.ico` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type of link from img/png to simple img as:

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image" href="assets/icons/homescreen-icon/group.png" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/icons/homescreen-icon/group.png" />
<link rel="mask-icon" href="assets/icons/homescreen-icon/group.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The below tag worked for me for both ios/ android on Angular 10 application in index.html file.

Note: make sure to follow the href path as below (in assets folder).

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-150x150.png" />
```